3D printed teffilin?
I realize that the hilchos of manufacturing tefillin are complex. Nevertheless, as an artist, I would like to design and produce my own.
Is it necessary that tefillin be made of leather? I get the sense that, asside from the parshas contained, that its necessary that they it be made of a single substance. If I produced the the tefillin retzuos from the same material as the tefillin shel rosh,is that OK, or does scripture necessitate the use of leather?
If this isn't kosher, knowing upfront will save me from diving into the literature in vain.
Shabbos shlaim.

The boxes, straps, and scrolls of tefilin must be made from animal hide of a kosher species. See here for more details.

What if you produced 3d printer ink from the hide of an animal of a kosher species?

@magicker72 Whoa, that is interesting.

Here is tefillin for sale made of bonded leather (which is similar to what 3D printed leather would be). Not terribly durable, but kosher for as long as it stays kosher https://www.shalomhouse.com/products/mehudar-tefillin-leather.htm
